# In a linked list, to Reach the last node via auxiliary links

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

We have a linked list with node structure:-

```
struct Node {
   Node *next;
   Node *aux;
};
```

structure of the linked list:-

1. next pointer always points to the next node, as in a singly linked list.
2. aux pointer can point to any node, before or after the current node, to current node itself, it can be NULL as well.

Problem statement:
Do **minimum** number of modifications to the aux pointers in the list, so that last node is reachable from any node of linked list via auxiliary pointers. e.g. Once all the modifications are done, restriction to reach the last node is that we can use only aux pointer to navigate the list.
Following is one of the possible representation of list. Note that aux pointer being NULL is not represented here.
[image]

Comment: Why voted to close it? Is this not a correct forum? or the question is flawed? You need to mention why! this is not very descriptive, rather it is crisp.

Comment: @StephenDocy thanks for your suggestion, tell me what is not clear? What is redundant and extra? How does it NOT convey efficiently the problem statement.

Comment: @StephenDocy Dont worry you are not capable to hand feed me of the code. and BTW i am on stackoverflow since long, its only when I get stuck with some good problems which can be asked on open forum, then only I ask it here. I have not included my solution here just to avoid approach bias of people who want to help. Its plain bullying that you are doing here. Previously you  had objections on the way i asked questions, and now some other stuff you are raising. Its absolutely of too much help for me if someone can comment with a good idea. I don't want any code here.

Comment: Though people have raised valid concern about this being very generic and no effort from original poster, I would like to throw my 2 cents over possible solution:

1. If there is any loop then break it, by simply pointing it to last node, 2. any node will null as AUX can be directly pointed to last node, 3. is bit tricky, perform DFS on rest of nodes, if last node appears in sequence do nothing move to next node is list, otherwise simply break at last and point it to one of previous nodes which were pointed to last.

Answer (score 0):

First a few observations:

The null aux pointers obviously need fixing, so just point them to the end.

For the others, if you keep following the pointers, they will either reach the last node so you don't need to do anything, or they will loop. If they loop then the elements on the loop will belong to exactly one loop (because you have a single aux pointer). You can pick any element of the loop to fix (since it's a loop all the other will eventually reach the fixed element).

There's no point in making a aux pointer point to anything other than the last element. That's the goal and pointing to anything else could potentially introduce a loop.

So with this mind the algorithm is simple:
Start with a vector of int where everything is 0. You'll need an id-generator (just an int to keep incrementing, starting at 1)

- Iterate through the vector.
- If the entry is not 0 move to the next entry in the vector.
- Otherwise get the next id from the generator (and increment it for
  the next time). Mark the node in the vector with the id and start
  following the aux links.
- If the next node is the last value then stop and resume iterating
  through the vector.
- If the next value of the next node is 0, mark it with the id and
  continue following the aux link from there.
- If the next value is not 0 and not the id you are currently using
  (you've reached a node you've already seen before) then stop and
  resume iterating throught the vector.
- If the next value is the id you are using then you've found a cycle.
  Fix the aux pointer of the current node and resume iterating through
  the vector.

Overall this solution has a complexity of O(N) because you will visit each node at most twice.